# Is there a difference between the two Map Assignments [] and putifabsent?

Tags: dart

Is there any performance or any other difference between defining [] or put if absent

```
map["x"] = 123;
map.putifabsent("z", ()=> 123);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from `map['x'] = 123` will overwrite the value for key`'x'` if it is already in the map whereas `map.putifAbsent('x', ()=> 123)` will not ?

Note that `putifAbsent` *returns* the value corresponding to the provided key. You can use it to get the value for a key, generating and inserting a value 'on the fly' if the key in missing from the map (which is why its second argument is a function, not a straight value).

It strikes me that this was the use case for the method, but the name `getValuePutIfAbsent` was deemed too long.

Comment: A likely source for the method name is the SmallTalk `at:ifAbsentPut:` message. Since the `[]` operator (the Dart version of SmallTalk's `at:`) doesn't take optional arguments, it had to be a method by itself.

Comment: So is `map.putIfAbsent('x', () => 123)` the same as `map['x'] ??= 123`?

Comment: The effect on the map and the value of the expression are the same. See https://dartpad.dartlang.org/766a368689d53496ee325aa589cf43e8. `putifAbsent` obviously predates `??=`.

Comment: It's almost the same, except if the map contains `null` as a value. In that case `??=` will assign, because `map['x']` returns null, but `putIfAbsent` will not because the map has `'x'` as a key. And that's why maps should not have null as a value.